# Got errors with discord.py cogs

Tags: python

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

@client.command()
async def reload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}') #line 22

client.run('token')
```

This is main discord bot.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Example(commands.Cog):
    
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Bot is online.')

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('Pong!')

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Example(client)) #line 18
```

and this is a example from cogs.
I have errors in line 18 in the example and line 22 in the main py
I'll  be so appreciated that you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest removing the section after client run just for privacy reasons on this site. People can easily change the code of your bot an mess things up. From line 18 I'd suggest removing the 'example' part of it. As for line 22, I will just say it's because there is no semi-colon in your whole project, of which is the line ending character. I would highly advise putting that after every line, otherwise it will read your entire set of functions at once. Since line 22 is the last line, it is telling you to make a semi-colon there.